# PHP Generating regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a function called accentToRegex, its so supposed to replace accented and non-accented letters to regex expressions. The only problem is that if I want to replace "s" to "[sš]" and "š" to "[sš]" (same thing). The function runs char by char and I end up with with something like this [s[sš]], when I input "s", however I would like to change that, so it returns only "[sš]".

I was thinking about running str_replace twice with modified values, but that seems inefficient.

So the question is how to change the function from running char by char and checking already inserted chars to ignoring the insterted chars.

Example. input="s" -> changes into "[sš]" -> changes "š" into "[sš]" so we get [s[sš]] instead of getting "[sš]".

```
function accentToRegex($pattern)
    {
       $replacements = Array("a" => "[aáàäâ]",
                             "e" => "[eéèëê]",
                             "s" => "[sš]",
                             "š" => "[sš]",
                              ....
                             );
       $flags = "iu";
       $times = 0;
       $final = str_replace( array_keys($replacements), $replacements, $pattern);  
       $regex = "/$final/$flags";
       return $regex;
    }
```

Thanks for your time and help, I appreciate it ;)

Comment: See the [strtr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) function -- one of the examples in the comments section is pretty much exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Answer found in [strtr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) function comments, the function is called gr_regexp(..).

```
function accentToRegex($mystring){
    $replacement=array(
            array("a","á","ä"),
            array("s", "š"),
    );
    foreach($replacement as $group){
            foreach($group as $character){
                    $exp="[";
                    foreach($group as $expcharacter){
                            $exp.=$expcharacter;
                    }
                    $exp.="]";
                    $trans[$character]=$exp;
            }
    }
    $temp=explode(" ", $mystring);
    for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($temp);$i++){
            $temp[$i]=strtr($temp[$i],$trans);
            $temp[$i]=addslashes($temp[$i]);
    }
    $flags = "iu";
    return "/".implode(".*",$temp)."/$flags";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your function with this:

```
function accentToRegex($pattern)
{
    $replacements = Array("a" => "[aáàäâ]",
                          "e" => "[eéèëê]",
                          "s" => "[sš]",
                          "š" => "[sš]",
                          );
    $flags = "iu";
    $times = 0;
    $final = strtr($pattern, $replacements);  
    $regex = "/$final/$flags";
    return $regex;
}
```